# How to view database and schema of django sqlite3 db

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-database

I'm new to django framework.

I tried to create a simple blog by following djangogirls tutorials.

Here by default, we get sqlite3 as default database Engine:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I tried some [ORM queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/) also, Even [performed some row sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/)

At my django project, I have this **db.sqlite3** file:

```
blog  db.sqlite3  env  manage.py  mysite
```

**My Question:** How to know the schema that django created in this db.sqlite3(I know mysql where I can see details about each database and tables, so here I just want to know more things in sqlite)

I have sqlite3 in my system and I tried .database command, but it just shows me:

```
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main
```

Comment: Did you try `.schema`?

Comment: Yes it shows blank. tried .help and all commands also

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Goto the folder where the database is and then

```
sqlite3  db.sqlite3
```

Then

```
.tables
```

or
.schema

depending on what you want. Instead of invoking sqlite3 directly you could do

```
 python manage.py dbshell
```

and then type the sqlite commands.

If you are working with a legacy database you can generate Django models for that using the

```
 python manage.py inspectdb
```

please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb for additional info.

But please do yourself a favour and get a GUI database client. Life is much easier when you have one.

Comment: Well yes all this assumes that sqlite3 is available on your system

Comment: `sqlite3` installs with `django` installation.

Comment: +1 for "please do yourself a favour and get a GUI database client. Life is much easier when you have one."  Preach.

Answer (score 10):

I have been stumbling around for an hour aiming to replicate `DESCRIBE` table inside the Django shell, and think I've cracked it. 
I hope this is of use to others.

In the Terminal - enter the following commands.

```
python3 manage.py dbshell
.tables
```

Find the name of the table you are looking for, then run the following commands:

```
.header on
.mode column
pragma table_info('table you are looking for');
```

Do not forget the semicolon in the last instruction.

Comment: and yes, forgot the semicolon at the end of the last instruction ;) Why is this line not blinking?

Answer (score 8):

First, run the command below:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

To access **sqlite3 command-line client** as shown below:

[image]

Then, run the command below:

```
.table
```

Or run the command below:

```
.tables
```

To show all the tables in **SQLite** as shown below:

[image]

Then, run the command below:

```
.schema --indent store_product
```

To show **the schema of "store_product" table** as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command to get the sql script for the database created.

`python manage.py sqlmigrate app_label migration_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can view your db.sqlite file online.
   [sqlite Online](https://sqliteonline.com/)

Just upload your file there and you can see your tables which are in your db.sqlite file.

Comment: My file not opening

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that someone can find the migrations under my_project_name>my_app_name>migrations and usually you pick the one with the biggest number.

Then the command should be like: `python manage.py sqlmigrate my_app_name number`